# Which objects will go to Stack and which to Heap and why?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does .net managed memory handle value types inside objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829/how-does-net-managed-memory-handle-value-types-inside-objects)

I have a class as below

```
public class MyClass
{

  public List<RequestRow> RequestRow { get; set; } 
  public List<int> intList { get; set; } 
  public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
  public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }

  int i;
  DateTime dt = DataTime.Now;

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
         //some operation
  }
}
```

The question is Which will go to heap and which to stack? And why?

Means MyClass , the properties, fields, and  the method will go where..heap or stack?

Recently I found this question in an interview and is curious to know about this

Edited

I liked Mr.John's answer and my doubts have been cleared..

I have 2 more questions to ask...

a) When will int i and DateTime dt be treated as Value type and will be put into stack

b) If I have an Interface say

```
namespace namespace1
{
    public interface IXLView
    {
        ExcelXP.Application ExcelApp { get; }
        ExcelXP.Workbook CurrentWorkBook { get; }
        ExcelVersion ExcelVersion { get; }       
    }

    public enum ExcelVersion
    {
        Excel2003, Excel2007
    }
}
```

**then where will be the objects be placed in this case..Stack or Heap?**
Thanks

Comment: Don't add new question(-part)s.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Which will go to heap and which to stack? And why?

Everything there goes onto the heap. Why? Because **the heap is for storage of data where the lifetime of the storage cannot be determined ahead of time**.  In your example the lifetime of everything - the numbers, the strings, the lists - cannot be known ahead of time, so they all have to go onto the heap so that the garbage collector can determine when that storage is dead.

> When will int i and DateTime dt be treated as Value type and will be put into stack?

They will always be treated as value types because they are value types. That is, they will be *copied by value* and *contain their own values*.

They will never be put onto the stack because the lifetimes of their storages cannot be known ahead of time.

> If I have an interface then where will be the objects be placed in this case ... stack or heap?

The question doesn't make any sense. You've only got *types*, no *objects*. What objects are you talking about?

But the answer is the same: the objects will be put on the stack if the lifetimes of their storages are known ahead of time; otherwise, they'll be put on the heap to be garbage collected.

Comment: If i define property in a class. Will it go to Heap ?

Comment: @Sudhir.net: You can answer that question. Is the lifetime of the value of the property known by the compiler ahead of time?

Comment: Some case known at compile time but some case it's known at the compile time. Below scenario known at compile time:                  private int _age = 10;

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }

Comment: @Sudhir.net: The lifetime of `_age` is not known at compile time. Its lifetime ends when the object holding it is garbage collected, which could be *never*, and therefore the lifetime is *not known to be short*.

Comment: Ok. But when we declare a local variable in a method ,it go into stack. how it's lift is known ? Why its going to stack?

Comment: @Sudhir.net: How long is the lifetime of a local variable, in a "normal" method -- that is, a method without await, yield or lambdas?  **Can it be longer than the activation of the method?**

Comment: it's life depends upon Method. But method life depend on class object. I want to understand because we say value type goes on stack , reference type on heap ,but it always not heppen.

Comment: The activation of a method depends on the lifetime of an object? How? You call a method. 5 microseconds later it returns. The object is collected five minutes later. How did the lifetime of the method's activation get tied to the lifetime of the object?

Comment: If 5 sec method life will end then how we can call method again through the object ? And whatever you have mentioned for method ,Same thing can applied to Property.Then how property lifetime depends upon object life time ?

Comment: If you call a method twice then you have *two* activations of the method. Do those activations have the same locals or different locals?

Comment: It will have different locals. But i can call property twice, it can have different locals .

Comment: @Sudhir.net: The value of a property is typically backed by a field, not a local. How is the lifetime of a field related to the lifetime of the object?

Comment: What is the meaning of locals here ? I have related this to making different calls?

Answer (score 6):

All of your variables are members of a reference type (`MyClass`), so they'll all be on the heap... at the moment.

However, as Eric Lippert is fond of saying, the heap and stack are implementation details. See these blog posts:

- [The stack is an implementation detail (part one)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx)
- [The stack is an implementation detail (part two)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx)
- [The truth about value types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

Comment: @Fredrik: I was busy adding the links :)

Comment: Comment replaced with upvote :)

Comment: Sir, thanks for the clarification.. I have 2 more questions to ask... a) When will int i and DateTime dt be treated as Value type and will be put into stack (b) If I have an Interface say public interface IXLView
    {
        ExcelXP.Application ExcelApp { get; }
        ExcelXP.Workbook CurrentWorkBook { get; }
        ExcelVersion ExcelVersion { get; }       
    }

    public enum ExcelVersion
    {
        Excel2003, Excel2007
    } then where will be the objects be placed?

Comment: @priyanka... int and DateTime will always be treated as value types, because that's what they are. I think you're still relating value types to the stack. Read the blogs!

Answer (score 0):

I think something's wrong here, the code you wrote will not push any variables on the stack. The stack will hold only hold variables (not all types) in a local scope or parameters, not calss members.

Comment: can you please site a sample example for me to understand better

Answer (score -4):

I believe that (please correct me if I am wrong) that structs / primitives (excluding strings) are allocated on the stack, while objects (that includes generics) are allocated on the heap.

Comment: Yup, I'm afraid you're wrong. For example, `i` and `dt` here are value types, but they'll still be on the heap because they're part of a class.

Comment: A correct statement is that structs are allocated on the stack when they are local variables or temporaries that are not closed-over locals of an anonymous method or lambda expression and they are not in an iterator block. In all other cases they are allocated on the heap.